# Need to append to the rest of the line between each tags

Tags: shell-script

I have a file like this:

```
<LocationMatch ^/raframework>
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WeblogicCluster xlytwv02-pub.sherwin.com:45330
WLIOTimeoutSecs 6000
Idempotent OFF
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch ^/biplus_webservices>
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WeblogicCluster xlytwv02-pub.sherwin.com:45330
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch ^/hr>
SetHandler weblogic-handler
WeblogicCluster xlytwv02-pub.sherwin.com:8530
WLIOTimeoutSecs 18000
Idempotent OFF
WLSocketTimeoutSecs 18000
</LocationMatch>
```

I need to modify it so it looks like: whatever value

```
  <LocationMatch ^/raframework>
  raframework:SetHandler weblogic-handler
  raframework:WeblogicCluster xlytwv02-pub.sherwin.com:45330
  raframework:WLIOTimeoutSecs 6000
  raframework:Idempotent OFF
  </LocationMatch>

  <LocationMatch ^/biplus_webservices>
  biplus_webservices:SetHandler weblogic-handler
  biplus_webservices:WeblogicCluster xlytwv02-pub.sherwin.com:45330
  </LocationMatch>

  <LocationMatch ^/hr>
  hr:SetHandler weblogic-handler
  hr:WeblogicCluster xlytwv02-pub.sherwin.com:8530
  hr:WLIOTimeoutSecs 18000
  hr:Idempotent OFF
  hr:WLSocketTimeoutSecs 18000
  </LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` filter that tracks the `<LocationMatch.../>` values and prefixes the intermediate lines should work:

```
awk '/^<LocationMatch \^/ {
  print $0
  m=substr($2,3,length($2)-3) ":"
  next
}
/^<\/LocationMatch>/ { m="" }
{ print m $0 }
'
```

In this loop `m` is the prefix (including the `:`).  We set it on the `<LocationMatch>` and clear it on the `</LocationMatch>` lines.  Any lines outside of them (including blank lines, and any lines before/after) should be left untouched.